# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at gn (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:2614)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

when i am trying to login , its showing error (Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded) whenever i am clicking on login its freezing and after 2 4 seconds showing error on console , i don't know what is actual issue , sorry for bad english

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEDZc.png)

[Second Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGzB0.png)

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span class="field_error" id="login_username_error"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span class="field_error" id="login_password_error"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" onclick=adminLogin() class="btn btn-default btn-block">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>




function adminLogin(){
            jQuery('.field_error').html('');
            var Username = jQuery("#username").val();
            var Password = jQuery("#password").val();
            var is_error = "";
            if (Username == '') {
                jQuery('#login_username_error').html('Please Enter username');
                is_error = 'yes';
            }
            if (Password == '') {
                jQuery('#login_password_error').html('Please Enter Password');
                is_error = 'yes';
            }
            if (is_error == '') {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "api.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "username": username,
                        "password": password,
                        "action": "Admin_sign_In",
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result.status);
                       if(result.status == true) {
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                        }else{
                            jQuery('.login_msgs p').html('Please Enter Valid Login Details');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
          
     
        }
```

Comment: Please do some debugging to find out when and where that error occurs. It's pretty hard to know from what you've posted. Is it before the ajax call? Is it after the ajax call? Do you have more javascript on the page? I don't really see anything obvious in the posted code that would throw the error you're getting.

Comment: However, I see a couple of typos. You define `Username` and `Password` but are then using `username` and `password` when sending the data. `Username != username`. Variables are case sensitive. That should throw a couple of "username/password not defined" errors though.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If not, please answer the questions I asked. If you have solved it, you can either write an answer yourself and accept that or delete it instead of just leaving the question hanging.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah I solved (You define Username and Password but are then using username and password when sending the data) this is tha issue i was facing its was a My mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function adminLogin(){
            jQuery('.field_error').html('');
            var username = jQuery("#username").val();
            var password = jQuery("#password").val();
            var is_error = "";
            if (Username == '') {
                jQuery('#login_username_error').html('Please Enter username');
                is_error = 'yes';
            }
            if (Password == '') {
                jQuery('#login_password_error').html('Please Enter Password');
                is_error = 'yes';
            }
            if (is_error == '') {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "api.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "username": username,
                        "password": password,
                        "action": "Admin_sign_In",
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result.status);
                       if(result.status == true) {
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                        }else{
                            jQuery('.login_msgs p').html('Please Enter Valid Login Details');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
          
     
        }
```

Comment: This also have the same typo in your `if`-statements. Honestly, I don't see how the variable issue would throw the error you posted though.